Proving $x_i \xrightarrow{s} 0 \iff x_i^*x_i \xrightarrow{w} 0$
I want to prove the following claim. First let me define the terminologies:

(Normal Form) A form $\varphi$ on a vNa $\mathscr{M}$ is said to be normal if it is $w$-continuous and positive.

Here the $w$-topology (or ultraweak topology) on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is the weak topology $\sigma(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}), \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_*)$ where
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_*:= \overline{\text{span} \{ \omega_{\xi, \eta} : \xi, \eta \in \mathcal{H}} \}.
$$

($s$-topology) This is the locally convex topology on $\mathscr{M}$ given by the seminorms $s_\varphi$:
$$
s_{\varphi}(x)=\varphi(x^*x)^{1/2}~~~ (x \in \mathscr{M})
$$
where $\varphi$ runs over all normal forms on $\mathscr{M}$.

Claim. For any net $\{x_i\}\subset \mathscr{M}$ one has
$$
x_i \xrightarrow{s} 0 \iff x_i^*x_i \xrightarrow{w} 0
$$
For $(\impliedby$), let $\varphi$ be a normal form. Then since $\varphi\in \mathscr{M}_*$, we get $\varphi(x_i^*x_i) \to 0$. Thus $x_i \xrightarrow{s} 0$.
I am stuck on the direction $(\implies)$: assume $x_i \xrightarrow{s} 0$ and $\varphi \in \mathscr{M}_*$. We need to prove that $\varphi(x_i^* x_i) \to 0$. By polar decomposition therem we get a normal form $|\varphi|$ and a partial isometry $v\in \mathscr{M}$ such that:
$$
\varphi = R_v |\varphi|~\text{ and } v^*v = \mathbf{s}(|\varphi|).
$$
Since $|\varphi|$ is normal so we have $|\varphi|(x_i^*x_i)^{1/2} \to 0$. From here how to proceed? Thank you.
EDIT. I think the convergency can be shown once we show it using only normal forms since any $w$-continuous form is a span of normal forms (by Jordan decomposition). Let $x_i \xrightarrow{s} 0 $. Now if $\varphi \in \mathscr{M}_*$ is normal, then $\varphi(x_i^*x_i) \to 0$. Hence for any $\psi \in \mathscr{M}_*$ we have $\psi(x_i^*x_i) \to 0$. Thus $x_i^*x_i \xrightarrow{w} 0$.
Is this modified argument right? Thanks.

Yes, the modified argument works. You can also use polar decomposition and Cauchy-Schwarz - $\varphi = R_v|\varphi|$, so$$\varphi(x_i^\ast x_i) = |\varphi|((x_i^\ast x_i)^{1/2}[(x_i^\ast x_i)^{1/2}v]) \leq [|\varphi|(x_i^\ast x_i)]^{1/2}[|\varphi|(v^\ast x_i^\ast x_iv)]^{1/2} = [|\varphi|(x_i^\ast x_i)]^{1/2}([L_{v^\ast}R_v|\varphi|](x_i^\ast x_i))^{1/2} \to 0$$where the final limit is because both $|\varphi|$ and $L_{v^\ast}R_v|\varphi|$ are normal forms.
